# Building Java Web-App with Vaadin in AWS

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have to write a (java) web-app, which fetches data from an AWS RDS Postgresql Instance, and renders the data using Vaadin Charts. So my two constraints are: (java) based, and using Vaadin to do so.

Thing is, I have never developped an form of web-app, and am complettely lost. I've read stuff about maven, spring, gradle , containers and am safe to say, have absolutely no clue where to start...
Could anyone point me to some complete tutorials about how to developp web aps from the ground up? everytime I google something I read something different and am completely overflown by information...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with something working ASAP you can clone existing repos with vaadin examples. You will have existing code that builds, manages dependencies, starts webserver etc:

https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples

https://github.com/vaadin/spreadsheet-demo

All the rest is probably opinion-based like *should I you use maven or not?* etc.